# Import with alias from Meteor Publish cursor doesn't work?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I need to create an alias from 'Import' because my React component as the same 'name' that my 'Import' collection.

**So, this work**

```
import Questions from '../../../api/Questions/Questions';
...
const subsQuestions = Meteor.subscribe('questions');
console.log(Questions.findOne());
```

**but I need an alias, and, this doesn't work**

```
import Questions as QuestionsAPI from '../../../api/Questions/Questions'; // error Unexpected token
or
import { Questions as QuestionsAPI } from '../../../api/Questions/Questions'; // error : undefined
```

**Can you help me please ?**

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just found :

```
import { default as QuestionsAPI } from '../../../api/Questions/Questions';
```